# weird compilation failure with overloaded const function and compiling with -pedantic

Tags: c++

The code below fails to compile.
if I remove the `bool foo(bool)` overload, then the `a.foo(&b);` call compiles.
if I remove the `const` qualifier from `bool foo(bool*) const;` then the `a.foo(&b);` call compiles.
While writing the question I found out that without `-pedantic` to gcc it also compiles
I can't understand why...

```
struct A {   

  bool foo(bool){
    return true;
  }
  bool foo(bool*) const {
    return false;
  }

};


int main() {
  A a;
  a.foo(true);
  bool b;
  a.foo(b);
  a.foo(&b); // does not compile
  const_cast<const A&>(a).foo(&b); // does compile
}
```

and the compilation error:

```
error: call of overloaded ‘foo(bool*)’ is ambiguous
   a.foo(&b);
           ^
/tmp/asdasd.cpp:4:8: note: candidate: bool A::foo(bool)
   bool foo(bool){
        ^~~
/tmp/asdasd.cpp:7:8: note: candidate: bool A::foo(bool*) const
   bool foo(bool*) const {
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, pointers are implicitly convertible to `bool`. So an overload set between a pointer and a `bool` will be ambiguous unless one of the overloads represents a perfect match on **all** parameters.

To better visualize the issue I extracted the member functions to free functions, which is basically the same thing:

```cpp
struct A {};

void foo(A&, bool) {}
void foo(const A&, bool*) {}

int main() {
    A a;
    bool x;
    foo(a, &x);
}
```

Neither of the function is a perfect match for `foo`, as the first one needs to convert the `bool*` into a `bool` and the second one needs to convert `A` to `const`.

Technically adding `const` would be a better match, but ISO C++ says it's still ambiguous in this case. When you remove `-pedantic` from gcc, it tells you exactly that:

```
<source>:9:9: warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:
    9 |     test(a, &x);
      |     ~~~~^~~~~~~
```

Also, `const_cast` is a bit of a big hammer for adding `const` as it can also remove `const`, which can be very dangerous. Better use [`std::as_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const) or implement your own if you can't use C++17 yet.